# Instantiating an ActiveX Object

Tags: c++, com, activex

I have imported an ActiveX library into my project in Visual Studio 2008 using:

```
#import "TeeChart8.ocx" named_guids
```

Now I would like to create objects exposed by the ActiveX library. However, I am having trouble understanding the API.

There are two files that were created after I built the project with the `#import`, a .tli file and a .tlh file.

In the .tlh file there is the following line:

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ITChart, __uuidof(ITChart));
```

I can see `ITChart` when I open the ActiveX library TeeChart8.ocx in the ITypeLib Viewer (Oleview). Also, if I type `ITChartPtr->Invoke` into my code, intellisense shows me that there are a whole bunch of parameters that need to be filled.

**Essentially, I would like to know how to instantiate an ActiveX object and where I have to look to get the information I need?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's a simple COM object, you can use the following (assuming a coclass named TChart to go with the interface named ITChart):

```
ITChartPtr chart(__uuidof(TChart));
```

For more information on using the `ITChartPtr` type defined by the `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF` macro in the .tlh file generated by the #import statement, see [`com_ptr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b%28VS.80%29.aspx).

If it's a full ActiveX control, there is more to it as [Victor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244026/victor) said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774647/instantiating-an-activex-object/3774824#3774824).

Comment: Yes there is a coclass named TChart. Are there additional includes I have to add apart from importing the .ocx file? As it is not building as it does not recognise ITChartPtr.

Comment: This worked with the help of this article http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/ab212d8a-d0f3-4d59-89c6-3051a4921470

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not enough to create ActiveX function CoCreateInstance.
ActiveX must be correctly initialized (Theory can be found here [ActiveX Controls Overviews and Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751969(v=VS.85).aspx) :-)

The easiest way is to use [CAxWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx242b61(VS.90).aspx) (ATL Framework)

Here, [collected various information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1stby863(v=VS.90).aspx) on how to create ActiveX controls

Answer (score 1):

Look up the function [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615%28VS.85%29.aspx) in your API docs.